# Stop chrome from overiding background-image with autofill

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, background-image

I have a problem where `Chrome` is overriding my `background-image` with it's autofill class.

I tried doing the below but it didn't have any effect:

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill
{
    background-image: inherit !important;
}
```

I didn't think this would work, but gave it a try anyway.

I know getting rid of the yellow color is easy enough, but how do you restore the image?

`JavaScript` or `jQuery` is fine if need be.

**Edit:** I should note that I can't use `!important` in the place where I am setting the background-image as weird behaviour occurs when I do that, though unsure if that is because I have the definitions separated such as `background-image`, `background-position` and `background-repeat` and I only used `!important` on `background-image`.